# Why nginx gzip_http_version defaults to HTTP 1.1

Tags: nginx

The default value for `gzip_http_version` setting in nginx's gzip module is HTTP 1.1. Why? Is there any problem with using gzip and HTTP 1.0?

Answer (score 9):

nginx gzip_http_version can have HTTP 1.0 and has it's caveats.

```
When HTTP version 1.0 is used, the Vary: Accept-Encoding header is not set. As
this can lead to proxy cache corruption, consider adding it with add_header.
Also note that the Content-Length header is not set when using either version.
Keepalives will therefore be impossible with version 1.0, while for 1.1 it is
handled by chunked transfers.
```

More here -- http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpGzipModule

Comment: The first sentence has been removed from newer versions of the documentation, so presumably it *does* now still send the Vary header.  But the impossibility of using keep-alive when gzipping on HTTP 1.0 (because the content-length cannot be known prior to output) still exists and there's no way around that.  So decide which is worse: HTTP 1.0 clients missing out on gzip, or HTTP 1.0 clients missing out on keep-alive (which often isn't possible for dynamic scripts on HTTP 1.0 anyway).

Comment: At the moment I believe the sensible setting is "1.0" - all it does is sacrifice keep-alive for HTTP 1.0 clients, and potentially affect caching for these clients.  Keep-alive isn't a mandatory (or particularly well-implemented) feature in HTTP 1.0 and HTTP 1.0's caching support is pretty limited anyway and very few real users will be using HTTP 1.0, they'd have to be going through a fairly old-fashioned proxy.

Answer (score 1):

It's most probably because HTTP 1.1 is the current version. There is little sense in defaulting to the previous version if the current verison is well adopted.

Comment: This setting does not control what HTTP version is used, it controls whether gzip should be disabled for HTTP 1.0 requests.